# Random Mesh Distortion Help!

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror, distort

so I cut my model in half to add a mirror modifier. Once applied I select the entire mesh, duplicate and seperate to create a body suit so to speak. 
To lift it away from the body I Alt-S just like the tutorial im watching and my mesh goes nuts! It looks like the mesh is trying to attach the some faces to the mirrored side.

Can anybody help??

Thank you 
will

[image: After pressing Alt-S]

Comment: maybe you're working on the mirrored side and not on the original side. Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I don't know why but what you said made me check something and it was what was causing the problems.

I had not turned off the x-mirror settings on the toolbar from when creating the mesh itself. 
Once I turned it off all of the problems stopped.